# How to load a div to external url using ajax when user has been logged from Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, authentication

This is my case now, If you could help me, thank you so much:
1. I logged in a Laravel application with a url: http://url1/ (this's authenticated)
2. Later from a url: http://url2/ from the same browser but out of the Laravel project  I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ( "#div1" ).load( "http://url1 #div2");
</script>
```

I need to load the div2 which is in laravel project into div1 placed out of laravel project.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/url1', 'Controller@categories');
```

This is the Controller.php:

```
public function categories() { 
    if (!Auth::id()) {
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
    $data = [];
    $data = $this->profile->getProfile();
    $member = $this->getCompany(Auth::id());
    $data->$member;
    return View::make('view1')->with('data', $data);
}
```

This is the view1.blade:

```
<div id="div2">
  {{$data->formatted_address}}
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

But how you can see I need to be authenticated when I do the call with load from the other website. 
How can I take the authentication that already I've done on Laravel project using the same browser to execute this function?

Comment: "How can I take the authentication that already I've done on Laravel project using the same browser to execute this function?"  -- This sounds like a huge security problem, so it is probably not a trivial task.  Would you want any webapp to be able to steal, say, your gmail session?